# Scrapy pagination

Tags: python, pagination, scrapy

I am facing a issue with scrapy pagination.

Here is the html:

```
<a href="" onclick="return false;" class="archive_page_info" 
id="next_achive_button" data-number_page_click="2">NEXT</a>
```

Scrapy python approach:

```
#follow pagination links
next_page_url =   response.css("#next_achive_button").extract_first()
if next_page_url:
   next_page_url = response
   yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

I need some help to solve this, when I click next button it should go to the next page. However, I see the next href is on `onclick="return false;"` I don't know how to do solve this issue. Could you please provide me with some hints how to solve the issue above. Thanks.

Comment: Click on next manually and see how the page url changes?

Comment: It probably executes some javascript when you click it. Can't say much more than that based on the information in your question. If you provide the URL of the page that you're trying to scrape, it's more likely people can help you out.

Comment: Thank you, Carter, here is the page https://therealdeal.com/new-research/topics/people/. If I click the next button stays in the same page but I think it is loading some javascript. It is possible to accomplish this through scrapy.

Comment: have a look at [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) and how to parse javascript navigation sites.

Answer (score 1):

Learn how to use `Inspect` in Chrome or Firebug if you have Mozilla.

Click on `Preserve Logs` and then click on next page button, you will see this AJAX POST being fired.

```
import requests

cookies = {
    '__unam': '7639673-16295793afa-1ab158d0-2',
    '__utma': '56229998.2107893981.1522926175.1522926175.1522926175.1',
    '__utmc': '56229998',
    '__utmz': '56229998.1522926175.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)',
    '__utmt': '1',
    '__utmb': '56229998.1.10.1522926175',
    '_first_pageview': '1',
    '__qca': 'P0-1006667184-1522926176233',
    '_jsuid': '585270328',
    'no_trackyy_100969001': '1',
    '__atuvc': '1%7C14',
    '__atuvs': '5ac6025f8fcb6eab000',
    '__tbc': '%7Bjzx%7DIafCBS3b0wpS60-QMtzjGoXcgB2LuqBv13vshDxFKXzUXsJfILJAOyJBA8fT0NrLuAw9JkikXT-lxGWsIpDKlbAJG-Kkoz0pLPzCOLd06VAHO90uO2kuCkU83cHKD7GRaOuzBb9gsuOCm70ShIsd5Q',
    '__pat': '-14400000',
    '__pvi': '%7B%22id%22%3A%22v-2018-04-05-16-02-58-224-d9oQ6Ns4C5cJ79uD-02aeb22c0032f00f6131c0dfebc6b934%22%2C%22domain%22%3A%22.therealdeal.com%22%2C%22time%22%3A1522926179784%7D',
    'xbc': '%7Bjzx%7DPVPoYpACRK8IQh-L66G6Lf11La8U3KDJG42A358oKni-AhQB0dxnTTq_CM95WKsZWHv9fY5JWLkSs5KImxmuRbiETxj07xc3lSSyb53w6bNyQuiiqqE20nVKEniUHDvl9zcfaHGMtBfOKaRmlxOx3TnX34PCjdEudjMUtEx_n9gwp4UEWknk1qUZNvvp7TLK-U4hyrWfMZZezw6MVfaRX5CZGW7Wg6zJ565EiqML9pJ9aeCUAUzgoy7pLjGXLxxtCBVOpfzQAi2b_SJnf2-Pe3KNCXlNvZ7Tr1GylPSVBkP1SYwS237iji2rMBo1YoeZ',
    '_eventqueue': '%7B%22heatmap%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22heatmap%22%2C%22href%22%3A%22%2Fnew-research%2Ftopics%2Fpeople%2F%22%2C%22x%22%3A795%2C%22y%22%3A3283%2C%22w%22%3A1366%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22heatmap%22%2C%22href%22%3A%22%2Fnew-research%2Ftopics%2Fpeople%2F%22%2C%22x%22%3A800%2C%22y%22%3A3268%2C%22w%22%3A1366%7D%5D%2C%22events%22%3A%5B%5D%7D',
}

headers = {
    'Origin': 'https://therealdeal.com',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Accept': 'text/html, */*; q=0.01',
    'Referer': 'https://therealdeal.com/new-research/topics/people/',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'DNT': '1',
}

data = [
  ('action', 'display_filtered_archives_of_trd_topics'),
  ('filtered_type', 'People'),
  ('number_of_click_page', '3'),
]

response = requests.post('https://therealdeal.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', headers=headers, cookies=cookies, data=data)
```

Comment: Thanks Umair got it so basically I have to make an ajax call request.post(ur, headers, cookies, data). Thank you so much.